# Create an object using Substring in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Ok, so, the idea is to create an object containing the latitude, longitude and zoom level data from a google map url, very simple:

```
function getMapData(url)
{
    let rawData = url.substr(url.search('@') +1, url.search('z')).split(',');
    const [lat,  lng,  zoom] = rawData;
    return {lat, lng, zoom};
}
```

Now, from my limited understanding, this should extract everything from `@` to the first `z` but I'm obtaining an object like this:

url example: `https//www.google.com.ar/maps/place/Central+Park/@40.7828647,-73.9675491,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x89c2589a018531e3:0xb9df1f7387a94119!8m2!3d40.7828647!4d-73.9653551?hl=en`

object created:

```
{
    lat: 40.7828647,
    lng: -73.9675491,
    zoom: 17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x89c2589a018531e3:0xb9df
}
```

So my question is: Why the *zoom* value is like this, why is not stopping at the letter *z*?

**fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/1yt5qnwf/4/

Comment: What will happen if your place name contains a z, like https//www.google.com.ar/maps/place/anyplacewithaz/@40.7828647,-73.9675491,17z ? Maybe you should consider using regexp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr), substr expects:

```
str.substr(start[, length])
```

What you really want is [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring), which expects:

```
str.substring(indexStart[, indexEnd])
```

Comment: OH! this is one of those moments where one feels completely stupid, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is working solution:

```
let rawData = url.substr(url.search('@') +1, url.search("z")-url.search("@")-1).split(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit dangerous to only look at @ and z position, as they can be found before (especially for Z wich can be in the place name). Here is a solution with regexp wich is imo less risky.

```js
var url = 'https//www.google.com.ar/maps/place/Central+Park/@40.7828647,-73.9675491,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x89c2589a018531e3:0xb9df1f7387a94119!8m2!3d40.7828647!4d-73.9653551?hl=en' ;

var regexp = /@([0-9-.]+),([0-9-.]+),([0-9]+)z/g ;
var match = regexp.exec(url) ;
console.log(match) // ["@40.7828647,-73.9675491,17z","40.7828647","-73.9675491","17"]

if ( match.length == 4 )
{
  match.shift() ;
  console.log(match) ; // ["40.7828647","-73.9675491","17"]
}
```

Comment: That's great, I already accepted an answer as correct bc it answers what a i was asking, now using regex is a very good idea, so i modified my function, and now it looks like this:`function getMapData(url)
{
 let regexp = /@([0-9-.]+),([0-9-.]+),([0-9]+)z/g,
  match = regexp.exec(url),
  rawData = match.shift().slice(1, -1).split(',').map(Number);
 const [lat,  lng,  zoom] = rawData;
    return {lat, lng, zoom};
}`

Comment: glad it can helps. You still can upvote if you think it's a good alternative. Have fun